# When does Image Layout Transition happen when no source or destination stage is specified

Tags: vulkan

Based on the specs https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/pdf/vkspec.pdf

It says "When a layout transition is specified in a
memory dependency, it happens-after the availability operations in the memory dependency, and happens-before the visibility operations"

As we know when calling `vkCmdPipelineBarrier(layout1, layout2, ...)`, the `srcAccessMask` is the availability operation and the `dstAccessMask` is the visibility operation. I wonder if I set both of them to 0, which means there is no availability operation and no visibility operation in this memory dependency, will there be any layout transition from layout1 to layout2 actually happening after the barrier call in this case?

To answer my own question:
Based on the specs, the queue present call will execute the visibility operation in this case.
https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkQueuePresentKHR.html
"Any writes to memory backing the images referenced by the pImageIndices and pSwapchains members of pPresentInfo, that are available before vkQueuePresentKHR is executed, are automatically made visible to the read access performed by the presentation engine. This automatic visibility operation for an image happens-after the semaphore signal operation, and happens-before the presentation engine accesses the image."
So we only need to write the src access to register an availability operation and leave the dst access 0(the visibility operation) to the present call.

Comment: I think it's meaningless. If you have no dstAccessMask stage then you have no observer to which the layout is made visible. If you have no valid observer then why does it matter what the layout is?

Comment: good question, the question was what I came across when I was trying to transition from color_attachemt layout to present_src layout after rendering to the swapchain image and trying to present it. because after rendering to the swapchain image I don't really have any other subsequent observer(i.g. no shader read of this image, or transfer etc). the only observer is the presentation engine. So I don't know what access mask or stage mask I need to use as the DST

Comment: @AnningWuwang That kind of layout transition from `ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL` to `PRESENT_SRC_KHR` is usually performed implicitly though the RenderPass attachments. So you don't need an image barrier for that. If, for some reason, you need to use a barrier, the srcAccessMask could be `VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT` and the dstAccessMask could be `VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT`. But I'm not 100% sure about the dstAccessMask

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the standard which says that the availability operations that are part of a memory dependency are optional. They always happen as part of executing the memory dependency. They can be empty and make nothing available, but it still always happens. The same goes for visibility.

So the layout transition happens regardless of what is available or visible. This is useful as any writes being consumed may have been made available before now by some other operation.

The bigger issue is the lack of visibility for operations down the line. A layout transition is ultimately a *write* operation. So processes that need to use that image need to see the image in the new layout. So it needs to be visible to them. So if you do this, you will likely see your validation layers complain later about some form of memory hazard.